# Export and Import FIle Content

Tags: c#, serialization, tree, out-of-memory

I have 2 class that are:

- Rep (for repositories)
- Files

Repositories have a collection of repositories and files. Files have a `list<string>` of lines.

I'm currently parsing repositories to construct my tree of folders and files (and file content).

I'm using binary serialization to export the all thing, but if files content is loaded I'm running out of memory.

What I want to achieve, is loading thousands of file to do quick search of string in it. I don't know what way would be the best in this case. I want to avoid that long moment of loading and "ReadAllLines()" on each file.

### Edit

I do have a lot of files to export, each file could contains many lines. I'm looking for a way to load it once a day. And loading it every time I use my searching application that needs to be as fast as possible. I was thinking about exporting binary files of my Repositories/Files/lines. And then loading it quickly every time I need :) Maybe I'm not thinking right, any ideas?

My code so far

```
[Serializable]
public class PlkFichier
{ 
    public List<PlkLigne> PNVLignes = new List<PlkLigne>();
    public List<string> PNVStrLignes = new List<string>();

    private string _PNVNom;
    private string _PNVRepertoire;
    private string _PNVExetension;
    public bool PNVChargerLignes;

    public string PNVRepertoire
    {
        get { return _PNVRepertoire; }
        set { _PNVRepertoire = value; }
    }
    public string PNVNom
    {
        get { return _PNVNom; }
        set { _PNVNom = value; }
    }
    public string PNVExtension
    {
        get { return _PNVExetension; }
        set { _PNVExetension = value; }
    }
    public PlkFichier()
    {

    }

    public PlkFichier(string pPath) : this(pPath, false) { }

    public PlkFichier(string pPath, bool pLoadLignesFile)        
    {
        PNVNom = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pPath);
        PNVRepertoire = Path.GetFullPath(pPath);
        PNVExtension = Path.GetExtension(pPath);
        PNVChargerLignes = pLoadLignesFile;

        if (PNVChargerLignes) this.PNVLoadLignesFile();
    }

    public void PNVLoadLignesFile()
    {
        string[] LignesLues = File.ReadAllLines(PNVRepertoire);
        PNVStrLignes = LignesLues.ToList();
        foreach (string vLignes in LignesLues)
        {
            PNVLignes.Add(new PlkLigne(vLignes));
        }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class PlkRepertoire
{
    public List<PlkRepertoire> PNVRepertoires = new List<PlkRepertoire>();
    public List<PlkFichier> PNVFichiers = new List<PlkFichier>();
    public string PNVNom;
    public bool PNVChargerArborescenceRep;
    public bool PNVChargerListeFichiers;
    public bool PNVChargerLignesFichiers;
    private List<PlkRepertoire> RemoveList = new List<PlkRepertoire>();
    private List<PlkFichier> NonSourceFiles = new List<PlkFichier>();
    private bool _NonSourceFilesVisible;

    public PlkRepertoire(string pNom) : this(pNom,false) {}

    public PlkRepertoire(string pNom, bool pLoadSubDirectory) : this(pNom, pLoadSubDirectory, false) { }

    public PlkRepertoire(string pNom, bool pLoadSubDirectory, bool pLoadListeFiles) : this(pNom, pLoadSubDirectory, pLoadListeFiles, false) { }

    public PlkRepertoire()
    {
    }

    public PlkRepertoire(string pNom, bool pLoadSubDirectory, bool pLoadListeFiles, bool pLoadLignesFichiers)
    {
        PNVNom = pNom;
        PNVChargerListeFichiers = pLoadListeFiles;
        PNVChargerArborescenceRep = pLoadSubDirectory;
        PNVChargerLignesFichiers = pLoadLignesFichiers;
        PNVLoadFiles(PNVNom);
    }

    public void PNVLoadFiles()
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("pnvLoadFies: " + PNVNom  );
        if (Directory.Exists(PNVNom))
        {             
            if (PNVChargerListeFichiers == true)
            { 
            string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(PNVNom);
            foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
            { 
                PNVAddFichier(fileName);
            }
            }
            if (PNVChargerArborescenceRep == true)
            { 
                string[] subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(PNVNom);
                foreach (string subdirectory in subdirectoryEntries)
                {
                    PNVAddRepertoire(subdirectory);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public bool IsEmpty()
    {
        return (this.PNVFichiers.Count == 0 && this.PNVRepertoires.Count == 0);
    }

    public bool NonSourceFilesVisible
    {
        get
        {
            return _NonSourceFilesVisible;
        }
        set
        {
                _NonSourceFilesVisible = value;
                this.PNVClearNonSourceFiles();
        }
    }

    /*
    public void ToXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        this.ToXml(writer,this.PNVRepertoires);
    }
    public void ToXml(XmlWriter writer, List<PlkRepertoire> ListeReps)
    {
        foreach (PlkRepertoire rep in ListeReps)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("Repertoire");
            writer.WriteElementString("Nom", rep.PNVNom);
            ToXml(writer, rep.PNVRepertoires);
            foreach (PlkFichier file in rep.PNVFichiers)
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("Fichier");
                writer.WriteElementString("NomFichier", file.PNVNom);
                writer.WriteElementString("ExtFichier", file.PNVExtension);
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }
    */


    public void PNVClearNonSourceFiles()
    {
        foreach (PlkRepertoire SousRep in this.PNVRepertoires)
        {
            SousRep.PNVClearNonSourceFiles();
        }
        foreach (PlkFichier FileASuppr in NonSourceFiles)
        {
            if (NonSourceFilesVisible)
            {
                if (PNVFichiers.Contains(FileASuppr) != true) PNVFichiers.Add(FileASuppr);
            }
            else
            {
                PNVFichiers.Remove(FileASuppr);
            }                
        }            
    }

    public bool PNVClearEmptyFolders ()
    {
        this.RemoveList.Clear();
        foreach (PlkRepertoire SousRep in this.PNVRepertoires)
        {
            if (SousRep.PNVClearEmptyFolders()) RemoveList.Add(SousRep);
        }
        foreach (PlkRepertoire RepASuppr in RemoveList)
        {
            PNVRepertoires.Remove(RepASuppr);
        }
        return this.IsEmpty();
    }


    public void PNVLoadFiles(string pRepertoire)
    {
        //if (pRepertoire.Contains(".xml")) PNVLoadFromXml(pRepertoire);            
        PNVNom = pRepertoire;
        this.PNVLoadFiles();
    }

    public void PNVToXml(string pathAndName)
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PlkRepertoire));
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(pathAndName);
        xs.Serialize(tw, this);
    }

    public void PNVToBinary(string pathAndName)
    {
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(pathAndName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            var binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, this);
            stream.Close();
        }
    }

    public static PlkRepertoire PNVFromBinary (string pathandname)
    {
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(pathandname, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();

            return (PlkRepertoire)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }


    public static PlkRepertoire PNVLoadFromXml(string pXml)
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PlkRepertoire));
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(pXml))
        {
            return  (PlkRepertoire)xs.Deserialize(sr);
        }
    }

    public void PNVAddRepertoire(string path)
    {
        this.PNVRepertoires.Add(new PlkRepertoire(path, PNVChargerArborescenceRep, PNVChargerListeFichiers, PNVChargerLignesFichiers));            
    }

    // Insert logic for processing found files here.
    protected void PNVAddFichier(string path)
    {
        PlkFichier vFile = new PlkFichier(path, PNVChargerLignesFichiers);
        if (vFile.PNVExtension != ".p" && vFile.PNVExtension != ".i" && vFile.PNVExtension != ".cls" && vFile.PNVExtension != ".lab" && vFile.PNVExtension != ".w" && vFile.PNVExtension != ".lep") this.NonSourceFiles.Add(vFile);
        this.PNVFichiers.Add(vFile);
    }

}

[Serializable]
public class PlkLigne
{
    public bool PNVIsEmpty;
    public string PNVLigne;

    public PlkLigne()
    {

    }


    public PlkLigne(string pCOntenu)
    {
        PNVLigne = pCOntenu;
        if (PNVLigne == "") PNVIsEmpty = true;
        else PNVIsEmpty = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

I would take advantage of `Lazy` loading your lines.  That will likely speed your calls up significantly and reduce memory.

```
private List<string> _pnvStrLignes;
public List<string> PNVStrLignes => _pnvStrLignes ?? (_pnvStrLignes = GetLignes());

private List<string> GetLignes()
{
    return File.ReadAllLines(PNVRepertoire).ToList();
}
```

So you're not having the constructor of your class read the entire contents of the file, rather only when you intend to use the property (which will hopefully be one at a time)

Comment: True, but i'm looking for a instant string research into my files. So I don't mind having a heavy/long loading. I'm trying to find a way to export this huge content, to import it next time so i don't have to do it more than once a day or week (depends). But having that speedy search is a requirement :/

Comment: `"I wan't to avoid that long moment of loading and "ReadAllLines()" on each file"`.  I was basing my recommendation on what you posted.

Comment: If you're loading this into a tree view control, you could limit search depth unless the node is expanded.

Comment: You right, I'll update my topic.
About the treeview, I probably will, not sure yet. The problem is that the first node contains about 5000 files. 
Would it be usefull to serialize repositories and files (without lines) and a binary file for each File (with lines).
So i could load my first binary file for the tree, and load all the line files using parallelisation?